# Maximum call stack size exceeded when trying patchvalue to a formControl

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to patch value to a form control when I select "select all" check box in a multi select drop down.when select all the options and then try to deselect all, "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error is shown.

```
<mat-select [formControl]="areaMultiCtrl" placeholder="Areas"  #multiSelect [multiple]="true">
      <ngx-mat-select-search [showToggleAllCheckbox]="true" (toggleAll)="toggleSelectAll($event)"  [formControl]="areaMultiFilterCtrl" placeholderLabel="Find area..." 
      noEntriesFoundLabel="'no matching area found'" 
      ></ngx-mat-select-search>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let bank of filteredAreaMulti | async" [value]="bank">
        {{bank.Name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

And select all executes this function.

```
toggleSelectAll(selectAllValue: boolean) {
this.filteredAreaMulti.pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(val => {
    if (selectAllValue) {
      this.areaMultiCtrl.patchValue(val, {emitEvent: false});
    } else {
      this.areaMultiCtrl.patchValue([], {emitEvent: false});
    }
  });
```

}

Any idea why this error occurs? I tried several fixes for this and non worked.

Comment: Where is `filteredAreaMulti` used ?

Comment: @AndreiGătej filteredAreaMulti is used to show options in drop down

Answer (score 0):

**Either** you don't need subscription in `toggleSelectAll` function

```
toggleSelectAll(selectAllValue: boolean) {
    if (selectAllValue) {
      this.areaMultiCtrl.patchValue(val, {emitEvent: false});
    } else {
      this.areaMultiCtrl.patchValue([], {emitEvent: false});
    }
}
```

**or** you should subscribe *once*, for example in ngOnInit

Comment: if i do this, error is still there.Is this something to do with my local setup?.

Comment: filteredAreaMulti has 400 records and if I slice it to 150, this works fine

Comment: Try `this.filteredAreaMulti.pipe(take(1))` in toggleSelectAll

Comment: I did this earlier and issue is still exist. 
`this.filteredAreaMulti.pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(val => {
        if (selectAllValue) {
          this.areaMultiCtrl.patchValue(val, {emitEvent: false});
        } else {
          this.areaMultiCtrl.patchValue([], {emitEvent: false});
        }
      });`